# JSON Web Token Authentication Permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am working on learning the basics of Asp.Net Web API and started to tackle the area of authentication. After doing some research it seemed that the right direction to go was OAuth2 and JWT so that is what I started to learn.
I have now ran through several tutorials, the final one being [here](http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/) which I found to be incredibly informative.

At this point I have a functional authentication server that issues JWT and a Web API endpoints that consume the tokens and even authenticate based on roles defined in the tokens. I feel that I have a solid understanding of the basics but it has left me with a questions that I haven't been able to find good answer to.

How do you handle a Web API that manages permission sets for multiple objects? A good example would be GitHub and repos; I could have different roles for each of the repos I have access to.

Originally I thought the solution was to just place a claim in the token for each repo with the permissions for that repo but it is possible for me to be a part of 100s or repos, that would have to result in a fairly large token.

I also considered a hybrid approach where put the claims in the token until a user belongs to some number of repos, say 10 for example, then I just put an indication in the token saying I need to query the db for the list of permissions.

I suppose both would work but neither of them feel right. I was just wondering if there was a best practice for this kind of use case and I'm sure someone has answered this before but I was having a hard time coming up with the correct search terms to get the answer. Thanks for any help you can provide.